# Converting String to &str with lifetime

Tags: string, rust, lifetime

I have a struct with one member:

```
pub struct Term<'a>(pub &'a str);
```

I also have a `Vec<Term>` and I want to convert the `Vec` to `Iterator` and then lowercase the `&str`, like:

```
pub fn add_vec(document: Vec<Term<'a>>) {
    let m_term = document.into_iter().map(
        |dx| Term(dx.0.to_lowercase().as_str())
    ).collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

but I'm seeing this error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/tfidf.rs:47:23
   |
47 |             |dx| Term(dx.0.to_lowercase().as_str())
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         - temporary value only lives until here
   |                       |
   |                       temporary value created here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 44:55...
```

I think I understand what the problem is, but I don't know how can I convert the `String` result of `to_lowercase()` to a `&str` with lifetime of `'a`.

Comment: You cannot. Since `to_lowercase` returns a `String` and nothing owns that `String`, any references to it will become invalid as soon as the closure ends and the memory is deallocated. That's why you get the error that the `String` doesn't live long enough. If you could, you'd end up triggering memory unsafety. Your only option is to return the `String`, transferring ownership of the allocation. That may involve you changing your `Term` struct likewise.

Comment: thanks @Shepmaster. What do you mean by returning the `String` and then transferring the ownership? could you please provide a short example?

Comment: Even better, there's an [entire chapter of *The Rust Programming Language* dedicated to ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ownership.html).